# how to make mutiple websocket channels?

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket, channel

Hello i using https://www.websocket.org/ , found some tuts in google about client & server sides, and make some readable php class for sockets and now i stop on progress..

I need create mutiple chanell support , ill try make this on protocols , but on second user connect owerwrite headers and all users above in same channels.

Anyone have ideas how to realize mutiple channels?

Client side - http://pastebin.com/1EKCzDFL
Server side - http://pastebin.com/cYbkDExM

Comment: Please post your code here to preserve it for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Then post only the relevant part.